# Using 'sfdp' to plot large graphs with perl-GraphViz2

Tags: perl, graphviz

My Perl scripts generates a very large graph with the module [`GraphViz2`](http://search.cpan.org/dist/GraphViz2/)

```
use GraphViz2;

my($graph) = GraphViz2 -> new
(
    edge   => {color => 'grey'},
    global => {directed => 0},
    node   => {shape => 'oval'},
);
add_very_many_nodes_and_edges();
$graph -> run(format => 'png', output_file => 'ptg.png');
```

`ps` tells me, that this script now runs `dot` to plot the PNG, but this takes several hours. `sfdp` is made for handling large graphs. How can I tell `GraphViz2` to use `sfdp`? I could not find anything in the documentation. The old `GraphViz` module has had the attribute `layout` to switch between `dot`, `neato`, `fdp` and `sfdp`.

Or is there any way to get a .dot file as output, as some kind of workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `driver` to solve your task. The `driver` option specifies which external program to run to process the output stream.